# Jeepers Creepers and the number 23

Tags: jeepers-creepers

In the film *Jeepers Creepers*, Jezelle points out that the Creeper seems to need to feed based around the number 23:

> "Every twenty-third Spring. For twenty-three days. It gets to eat".

Is it known if there is any significance the number 23 given by the author, Victor Salva?

Comment: in-universe or out? Salva claims not to know where the number came from, other than that he finds it inherently spooky *"I'm not sure where the 23 came from, but my room-mate tells me he noticed that on the noticeboard across from my desk when I was writing the script there was a big number 23, kind of like in The Usual Suspects, with a red circle around it, and it was the poster for the 23rd Annual Gay & Lesbian Film Festival, so perhaps that was a subliminal influence. But I think 23 is also a kind of scary number, though I'm not sure why."* - https://tinyurl.com/p6a5ddyk

Comment: It is a prime number, much like [periodical cicadas](https://www.mathnasium.com.hk/2016/04/math-in-nature-a-prime-life-cycle-for-periodical-cicadas) although honestly, with one Creeper, there's no reason for the prime number for cycles.

Comment: Lol. Salva wrote and directed both sequels. He can’t have hated the idea _that_ much.

Comment: I'm surprised that no one mentioned [The Illuminatus! Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Illuminatus!_Trilogy) yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't found a direct quote, but out of universe, [IMDB](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0301470/trivia/?ref_=tt_ql_trv) notes:

> Victor Salva wrote the "Every 23 years for 23 days it gets to eat" rule in Jeepers Creepers (2001) so there would be no sequel unless the movie was set in the future, and he knew the studio wouldn't want that. However Francis Ford Coppola found an easy loophole: set it during the same 23 days as the first movie. So this movie is set on the 23rd day for the purpose of not making another sequel.

Comment: I think the quote is from the featurette "The Making of Jeepers Creepers 2" which came on the DVD release of JC 2. Ironic that the explanation would actually come on a sequel...

Comment: see the first 20 seconds here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eb1wrHMf7io

Comment: Ready for Jeepers Creepers 4 in 2024? ;)

Comment: @Adamant: Supposedly, the fourth one is coming out in 2021 under a different director. *Jeepers Creepers: Rebirth*.

Comment: @Fuzzyboots - Is it another interquel?

Comment: @Adamant: It looks like maybe a sequel? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeepers_Creepers:_Reborn